# Sentiment analysis comparing two lists assigning sentiment scores. JSON ValueError

Tags: python, dictionary, sentiment-analysis

I am quite new to python

Here is my problem. I want to compare a csv file(message_ID,Comment) which contains sentences with words that have a sentiment score (word,score) . The output at the end should give a score of each sentence depending on which words were hit. I read online that one should use json even when reading otherfiles because of the in-built functions it provides.

#### data.csv:

1,there is a great recession

2,great things happening

#### sentiment.txt:

recession, -0.58

great, 0.15

#### output:

1,there is a great recession, -0.43 *(-0.58+0.15)*

2,great things happening, 0.15

I receive this error when executing the code:
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 - line 2 column 1 (char 1 - 72)

```
import csv
import json

scores = {}  

with open('sentiment.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        scores[row[0].strip()] = float(row[1].strip()) 


with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        text = tweet.get('text','').encode('utf-8')
        if text:
            total_sentiment = sum(scores.get(word,0) for word in text.split())
            print("{}: {}".format(text,score))
```

The main part of the code I got from [how to properly loop through two files comparing strings in both files against each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391808/how-to-properly-loop-through-two-files-comparing-strings-in-both-files-against-e)

Thanks for your help

Comment: JSON is a data format, just like CSV is (although CSV is less standardised, which is why JSON is often recommended). It isn't a thing with built in functions. You cannot use the `json` module to read a CSV file. Stick to the CSV reader: use `for row in reader` and not `for line in f` and don't use `json` at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex went and did that. Do you know by chance what the command would be for csv to do the comparison between the two lists?

Comment: How big are these files? It might be easiest to just read them all in memory and then you don't have to think in files and CSV at all, just plain python lists.

Comment: The csv file contains about 52000 rows (12MB). I could split the file but I don't know what the memory limit is for python.

Comment: 12 MB is very small. So you can read it all in at once: `with open('data.csv') as f: rows = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'))`. Then `rows` will be a list where each element is also a list representing a row. If after that you still can't solve your problem then post a new question on SO and provide sample lists, so CSVs don't have to be involved in the issue.

Comment: Okay great I will try it! Thank you Alex for your help. Much appreciated